# 3D displacement measurement of a small object with sub-micron accuracy

Tags: measurements, optics, lasers, distance-measurement, metrology

Say we have a small object for which we can choose its geometry and material (e.g, a spherical mirror with 5mm diameter). Or alternatively a point wise light source generating spherical waves.

The point is we want to measure its 3D displacement with sub-micron accuracy and high frequency and the working space may be from 10 to 20 cm from the measurement setup. and the displacement may be around 5cm.

Most of measurement devices that I have come across with and have such accuracy/speed use collimated light source (directed line), e.g., using interferometry, triangulation, etc.

My ultimate goal is attaching this sphere to another larger object to measure its displacement, or have more sphere and measure the pose with such accuracy and speed.

Is there any commercial solution that allows such measurement, given the flexibility described above, or what physics principles do you think would be best for it?

Comment: Sounds like a PhD thesis to me.

Comment: shopping questions are not allowed here ... please ask a question about the problem, not about a commercially available solution to the problem

Comment: @jsotola I don't even know if it's possible. Would be of course glad if even a commercial product is available, because it is somehow a proof of concept. like the question mentions, I have also asked what a potential physics principle for it is. It's not at all a shopping question, I only want ideas, that are hopefully also proven

Comment: Check out ABB, they can position a cue tip in 3D very precisely with repeatabilty. https://youtu.be/nH08-JQwsZQ

Comment: Maybe you can use interferometry at a high enough sample rate to actually track the object. If you can measure at 1khz, and you use 1000nm infrared light the object could be tracked up to 1mm per second.